# Implementing multithreading - Tweepy

Tags: python, flask, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Is it possible to use multithreading in Tweepy streaming? The code I am using is not working fine (not showing the data every time I refresh my page).

Thank you in advance, regards.

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(myaplkey, myappsecret)
auth.set_access_token(mytokenkey, mytokensecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

stream_listener = tweepy.StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(track=["mysearch"], a_sync=True)
stream.filter(track=settings.TRACK_TERMS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tweepy v3.10, you can use the `is_async` parameter of `Stream.filter`.
See https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streaming_how_to.html#async-streaming.

In the development version on the master branch, this has been changed to `threaded`.
See https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming.html#threading.

You'll also want to subclass `StreamListener`, as by default, it doesn't output anything.
Refer to the [Streaming With Tweepy section of the documentation for v3.10](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streaming_how_to.html) for more information.